# Does it matter which order options are entered when using the command line?

Tags: linux, centos7, command-line-interface

**Question:** Does it matter which order options are entered when using the command line?

The following example comes from CentOS.  Would these two commands produce the same result?

`sudo yum update -y`

`sudo yum -y update`

Is there a page that explains the general syntax rules for the command line?  I can't seem to find one that explains if/how order impacts outcome.  Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That does entirely depend on the program and sometimes the type of parameter. In your example, it doesn't matter, but there exist programs that needs parameters in a certain order. Also, even with `yum` as an example, `yum install somepackage` would work but `yum somepackage install` would not.

When in doubt, consult the documentation of the program in question (e.g. `man yum`).

Comment: Thanks!  As long as I know each program may be a little different that's a rule I can remember.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific rules for this case.
Parameter `-y` means, that you answer "Yes" to any questions.
From yum manpage:

> -y, --assumeyes
>
> Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.

Usage of yum:
`yum [options] [command] [package ...]`

But you may put options anywhere you want:

```
yum install -y nagios-plugins-perl.x86_64 -e 1 nagios-plugins-ifstatus.x86_64
```

where -e 1 - debug level

This command will work properly due to argument parsing.

Comment: Does CentOS know to apply the `-y` to `yum` and not to `update`?

Comment: @DR01D: The OS (or better the shell starts `yum` and sends it the parameters which where used when starting it. It's only the job of the program to make sense of these parameters, the shell doesn't care at all.